# fill_n vs memset to set default value of an array

Tags: c++, memset

I wonder what is the ideal way if you want to fill an array with a default value n:

```cpp
#include <cstring> // for memset
#include <algorithm> // for fill_n

static constexpr int N = 100;
int a[N];
static constexpr int defaultValue = -1;
```

`void* memset( void* dest, int ch, std::size_t count );`

```cpp
memset(a, defaultValue, sizeof(a));
```

> (memset) converts the value ch to unsigned char and copies it into each of the first count characters of the object pointed to by dest. If the object is a potentially-overlapping subobject or is not TriviallyCopyable (e.g., scalar, C-compatible struct, or an array of trivially copyable type), the behavior is undefined. If count is greater than the size of the object pointed to by dest, the behavior is undefined.

or

`constexpr OutputIt fill_n( OutputIt first, Size count, const T& value );`

```cpp
fill_n(a, N, defaultValue);
```

> (fill_n) assigns the given value to the first count elements in the range beginning at first if count > 0. Does nothing otherwise.

I am looking for insights, I know how to read the documentation of course!

edit: defaultValue might not be only -1.

Comment: For trivial types, `fill_n` will probably result in a `memset`-like operation under the hood and for other types, `memset` will not be able to copy objects into place. I'd stick with `fill_n`. In works for both.

Comment: Depends on what you really want to do. `memset` works on bytes, so -1 is written into every single byte in the array of `int`s. This is OK with -1 because 4 bytes of -1 has the same bit pattern as one `int` set to -1. Try that with 1 and you get, assuming 32 bit `int`, an array full of of 16843009  (0x01010101).

Comment: With respect to the edit, and my above comment, it sounds like `fill_n` is the only option if you want each `int` in the array to have `defaultValue` as the default value. Also consider what if `defaultValue` is too large to fit in a single byte. `memset` is completely useless in this case because it'' lop the given value down to an `unsigned char`..

Comment: your point was very interesting nevertheless, you can add it in your (formal) answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both functions do different things. Sure, they fill a block of memory, but the way they do it is completely different.

`memset` operates at the byte level. `defaultValue` is hacked down to an `unsigned char`, so a `defaultValue` greater than what can fit into a single byte gets cut down to size and information is lost. The now-byte-sized value is applied individually to every byte, not every `int` in the array. In the case of -1 you get "lucky" because four bytes worth of 0xFF looks the same, 0xFFFFFFFF, as a two's compliment -1 in the world of 32-bit integers. No such luck for most other numbers. 1, for example, will not result in an array full of `int`'s set to 1, it's filled with 0x01010101, or 16843009.

`fill_n` , on the other hand, respects the array element's type. Every `int` in the array will be set to `defaultValue`.  in the case of a `defaultValue` of 1, the array will be full of 1s. `defaultValue` of 256, provides an array full of 256.

In terms of speed, it probably won't matter much. Memory read or written in bytes is a rare sight these days. Writing whole `int`s at a time may be faster. But a good `memset` implementation knows this and will be exploiting it. If it doesn't, the compiler likely will.